AWS EKS Node Group Created EC2s not showing up as Nodes
I have created an AWS EKS cluster through the AWS Management Console.  I setup multiple node groups within the cluster, each with its own autoscaling group.  When I go to the EC2 Instances in the Management Console, I see that there are EC2s that have been created by the autoscaling groups.  However, these EC2s do not show up as Nodes in the EKS Cluster in the Compute tab of the Cluster page nor the Nodes tab of the Node Group page.  When I run kubectl get nodes, "No resources found" is returned.
Is there a setting I'm missing on the node groups to ensure these EC2s properly show up as nodes?

Better SSH into the Worker Node (EC2 Instances) and checkout the kubelet status by running journalctl -u kubelet
